# How to access Docker Container with Clickhouse in Windows for loading data?

Tags: powershell, docker, clickhouse

I am interested in loading data into a docker container with clickhouse currently running in windows docker desktop. I have built my tables and prepped the data in R in .csv format but now want to load the data using the system instead via R or Python. In Ubuntu I have done this before without docker using code from this blog to load into my clickhouse database:

https://tech.marksblogg.com/billion-nyc-taxi-clickhouse.html

```
 time (for filename in /home/mark/trips/trips_x*.csv.gz; do
            gunzip -c $filename | \
                python trans.py | \
                clickhouse-client \
                    --query="INSERT INTO trips FORMAT CSV"
        done)
```

How would I go about implementing a similar procedure with windows bash or powershell while accessing the docker container? Now I am in windows so I have clickhouse dockerized and running there.

EDIT

my files are in csv format so here is my first attempt:

```
#loop through files
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\testing_load"

foreach ($f in $files){
    $outfile = $f.FullName | Write-Host `
    docker run -it --rm --link chanalytics:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server `
    INSERT INTO trips FORMAT CSV

}
```

trying to invoke the insert command on each csv file in the directory

Comment: Are you looking for `--host` and `--port` options of `clickhouse-client`?

Comment: If necessary to access via powershell then yes. currently clickhouse server is running on 8123 in the local host which I set using --port. Clickhouse client is able to access that port without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
Figured it out I think:


#loop through files
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\testing_load"

foreach ($f in $files){
    $outfile = $f.FullName | Write-Host
    Get-Date | Write-Host    
    "Start loading" + $f.FullName | Write-Host
    docker run -it --rm --link chanalytics:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO trips FORMAT CSV"
     Get-Date | Write-Host 
    "End loading" + $f.FullName | Write-Host
}
```

Comment: As evidenced by the linked follow-up question of yours, this is not effective - no input is being passed to the `docker` command (even though you fixed the problem with you're passing the query string).